# int and Integer affect the concurrency results

Tags: java

There is a simple code abort concurrent. 
The type of i change from int to Integer ,the program run in a different way.
 It will not stop using int ,and stop in Integer. also I change some other way .such as add printf or replace while condition with True .then it act unnormal

then u can try these condition

1. do not change anything, the code will run forever
2. change  the type of i from int to Integer. the program will end in few second
3. keep the type of i be int ,and add a  `System.out.println(String.valueOf(i))` .then the program will end after print 228273 . the value will be change for example 222889\226074 and so on
4. change the while condition to true not !stopRequested. then the program will run forever .the type of i is not decision

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   public class StopThread {
       private static boolean stopRequested;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   int i = 0;
                   while (!stopRequested) {
                       i++;
                       //System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
                   }
               }
           });
           t.start();
           TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
           stopRequested = true;
       }
   }
   ```

so can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: I got -2147483648 (it's `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) for `Integer` and nothing for `int` (program not stopped).

Comment: So I think it may be relate with signed integer overflow behavior for `Integer`. PS: I transfer `println` to next line. Another strange: for  `Integer i = Integer.MIN_VALUE` (or `MAX_VALUE`), I got -128 (`BYTE.MIN_VALUE`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the Java Memory Model doesn't provide any guarantee that what you write in a thread is visible to another thread if you don't have proper synchronization.

Your `stopRequested` variable should be volatile, or it should be accessed inside a synchronized block, or it should be an `AtomicBoolean`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Comment: This is true, but does not answer the question at hand. The type of `i` should not affect the runtime behaviour, but at least in my local tests (AdoptOpenJDK, 8.0.212.03), it did and I was able to replicate the behaviour OP mentioned (with `int` and without printing -> endless loop, with `Integer` -> termination after ~1 sec, with `int` and printing -> termination after ~1 sec)

Comment: @Turing85 and OP are right I am observing the same behavior.

Comment: @Turing85: There's no "should not" here - the fact that there are no guarantees around what is visible means that any change, even if it might *appear* unrelated, is permitted to affect the visibility.

Comment: It could work with int, too. And it could not work with Integer. The JVM is free to do whatever it wants as long as it respects the guarantees of the JMM. Something, somewhere, causes memory to be flushed and become visible. But relying on this is foolish, because the visibility is only guaranteed with proper synchronization. On my machine, with Integer, it takes more than 5 seconds before the program stops.

Comment: "The type of `i` should not affect the runtime behaviour". Why not? As soon as you have undefined behaviour already (due to lack of synchronization) all bets are off. Seemingly unrelated changes in things like heap memory access patterns (which an `Integer` needs to be allocated on) could very well cause that.

Comment: I suspect the reason in this particular case is that `i++` can be done with no method calls when `i` is an `int`, so the JVM doesn't need to consider what any other code does... whereas as soon as you make *any* method call, including the implicit call to `Integer.valueOf`, those optimizations aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

While not explicitly stated, I think that JB Nizet has the root cause in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57831485/4216641). As was stated in said answer, the synchronization in OPs program is not guaranteed to work correctly, since `stopRequested` is not set `volatile`, thus synchronization could or could not happen for any reason.

What I think happens is this:

- If you use an `Integer`, the increment needs to fetch and write from and to memory. This could lead to `stopRequested` being updated from memory / invalidated in cache and thus termination "works".
- In case of just `int`, there is no write to memory (stack variable), thus `stopRequested` does not get updated
- I am quite sure that within `System.out.println(...)` some objects are read and/or created, thus you have the same effect as in the first bullet point, and `stopRequested` gets updated.

In any case, this is all undefined behaviour, could change any time for any reason and should not be relied up on.